# What is the syntax for an interface method when using MarshalAs

Tags: c#, asp-classic, marshalling

I am trying to create a COM object that has a method in it.  The method returns an array which has to be marshalled because it is being used by Classic ASP.

I have found questions on stack overflow that show me how to do it for properties but not for methods.

This is what I have tried:

```
public interface IMine
{
  [DispId(1)]
  object stringSize(string txt, string fontName, float fontSize)
  {
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY)]
  }
}
```

It's clearly wrong as I'm getting the error:

```
The name 'MarshalAs' does not exist in the current context
```

which means nothing to me.

The actual method is:

```
    public object stringSize(string txt, string fontName, float fontSize)
    {
        System.Drawing.SizeF result = _textSize(txt, fontName, fontSize);
        return new object[] { result.Width, result.Height };
    }
```

Somebody please correct my syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the attribute target definition **above** the method declaration:

```
public interface IMine 
{ 
  [DispId(1)]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_ARRAY)]  
  object stringSize(string txt, string fontName, float fontSize) 
  { 
    // stuff...
  } 
}
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something stupid that I'd done - cheers will try it tomorrow